# TypeScript - property does not exist on type (but it exists)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, strong-typing

I have a type of User that contains some user data. There's also a type of UsersResponse which basically is `users: User[]`. So far everything is easy. The problem is I have to pass UsersResponse as props and then I can't access `.users`. Why is that?

[Link to Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/create-react-app-typescript-forked-hweiq?file=/src/index.tsx).

Part of the code:

```
export type User = {
  login: string;
  password: string;
}

export type UsersResponse = {
  users: User[];
}

export interface MyProps {
  props: UsersResponse;
}

const App = (props: MyProps): any => {
  console.log('props: ', props.users);

  return (
    <>foo</>
  );
}
```

Console.log fails because `Property 'users' does not exist on type 'MyProps'.`

But this makes no sense to me, because MyProps returns UsersResponse and it has `users`. What am I missing here? How do I fix that? I know it's something really obvious or I made a typo, but really, I can't find it. Note I have to use `props: type` as this format is forced by the framework I'm using.

Comment: Shouldn't it be MyProps.props?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had set the wrong key in `MyProps` interface.

And you also don't need to declare `UsersResponse`.

Try this:

```js
export type User = {
  login: string;
  password: string;
}

export interface MyProps {
  users: User[];
}

const App = (props: MyProps): any => {
  console.log('props: ', props.users);

  return (
    <>foo</>
  );
}
```

Comment: I want to stick to `UsersResponse` because I will be using it across many components. The worst part is I can't replace `props` with `users` as you suggested because the props come in a form of `props: {data}` and I'm getting this error: `Type '{ props: any; }' is not assignable to type 'MyProps'.` :( Any other hints? Shouldn't my original example just work?

Comment: In that case, just rename `MyProps` to `UsersResponse` (also for `props: UsersResponse`). Then you can re-use it wherever you'll need it.